# PHP Include without Parent CSS Being Applied

Tags: php, css, include

I have index.php which uses its own style.css.

I'm including helloworld.php which uses style2.css and JavaScript (it's an image gallery).

When I include helloworld.php on index.php, style2.css gets completely ignored and seemingly not loaded at all. And when I copy the contents of style2.css into style.css, I get the same results - nothing from the included file gets styled properly.

I'm a little bit new at this - is this even possible?

Comment: Ignore the PHP part entirely for the moment. The only thing that matters is the HTML that gets output. Please show the `head` section of the resulting HTML file

Comment: See my response below with links to code plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you including the link to the other style sheet in your headers on idex.php? Try this.

examples (place inside open / closing tags)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/style1.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/style2.css">
```

Comment: This is helloworld.php (actually called portfolio.php I was just using helloworld as an example for the question): http://monobin.com/__m571a1914  ---------  This is index.php. http://monobin.com/__m6f87811f  --------- As you can see here, it completely ignores all CSS: http://veronicacole.ca/index.php?page=portfolio -------

When really, it's supposed to put in an image gallery similar to this: http://veronicacole.ca/gallery/demo.html

Comment: For the record, I'm not being paid for this site and as you might have guessed I'm not a professional by any stretch so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is the path to your second css correct? try taking the link out of the gallery php code. type your url followed by that path to  see if it shows up or you get an error. finally, try moving gallery's css file to your css folder and linking to it like your main css.

Comment: I corrected my issue. The files were all pointed correctly, but it magically worked when I put it in the main root folder and linked it again from index.php. Thank you!